# Importing tab-delimited text file - can't change the column mappings SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a very large tab-delimited text file I'm trying to import into SQL Server 2008.  Some of the field names are greater than 50 characters and when I try to change the column mappings using Management Studio, I'm unable to change the data type (default is varchar) or the size (default is 50).  The Edit SQL button is also grayed out.  What gives with this?

I am importing the data through the import wizard in SSMS (right click on database name, tasks, import)

Comment: How are you importing the data?

Comment: with the import wizard provided through SSMS

Comment: Assuming you are using the Flat File Source, have you tried changing the types and sizes in the "Advanced" page? Are you getting an error or are the fields disabled?

Comment: Perfect.  I'm new still SQL Server and I'm learning on the job.  This worked perfectly.  If you formally answer the question outside of this comment, I'll accept it.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, if you run the wizard and you get an error, it creates a table.  You have to go into SQL, delete the table and then start over.  Otherwise, SQL Wizard does not allow you to edit the table once it has been created.